# os.system giving weird output in linux

Tags: python, linux, os.system

I am running this python function in suse linux to grep ip of node from /etc/hosts--

```
def mm_node():
    import os
    node_name = os.system("`cat /etc/hosts | egrep -i mm | grep om | awk '{print $1}'`")
    return node_name

mm_node()
```

As a result, it is showing this weird output

```
sh: 192.168.10.10: command not found
```

instead of

```
192.168.10.10
```

If I run the shell command

(`cat /etc/hosts | egrep -i mm | grep om | awk '{print $1}'`)

directly on linux command prompt, it gives the o/p as

`192.168.10.10`

Comment: Remove the backticks from the system string command: `"cat /etc/hosts | egrep -i mm | grep om | awk '{print $1}'"`

Comment: Why did you have backticks here in the first place? Serious question; I don't think we have a canonical instance to close this common mistake as duplicative of, but we really should. I can't write a convincing instance, though, without understanding why anyone ever writes this code in the first place, and I've never seen an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Backquotes tell the shell to capture the output and use it on the command line, typically as argument to a command, as in `` grep `whoami` /etc/passwd ``. In your case the command line consists *only* of a backquoted pipeline, so the shell interprets the output of the pipeline as the command to execute. That is why it complains that the IP address is "not found".

If your intention is to capture the output of the pipeline to use in your Python code, you should use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module, which is the modern alternative to `os.system` that allows easy capturing of the output. For example:

```
import subprocess

def mm_node():
    output = subprocess.run(
        "cat /etc/hosts | egrep -i mm | grep om | awk '{print $1}'",
        shell=True,
        capture_output=True
    ).stdout
    return output.strip()

print(mm_node())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mm_node():
    import os
    node_name = os.system("cat /etc/hosts | egrep -i mm | grep om | awk '{print $1}'")
    return node_name

mm_node()
```

Comment: Note that it would be more efficient to just run `awk '/mm/ && /om/ { print $1 }' </etc/hosts` and not need cat or grep at all.

Comment: This won't work because `os.system()` returns the status of the finished process, not its output.

Comment: Heh, that too. Really should switch to `subprocess.run`.